TCP Client to NestJS Microservice Fails to Get Response
I’m working on a custom tool called SendStorm that includes a TCP client for querying microservices. The tool itself is not focused on NestJS, but now I am testing it with Nest. The goal is to send JSON-formatted messages to the server and receive a response.
What I'm Trying to Achieve
The client sends a message like this:
{
  "pattern": "get-all-platforms",
  "data": {}
}

The server should process this message and respond.
Server Code
The server is implemented using NestJS and @nestjs/microservices. Here is a simplified version:
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @MessagePattern('get-all-platforms')
  handleMessage(data: any) {
    console.log('Received data:', data);
    return { message: 'Success', data };
  }
}

The server starts successfully and accepts TCP connections. When I interrupt the client (e.g., using Ctrl+C), the server logs the disconnection, confirming that the connection was established.
Client Code
Here’s the TCP client implementation:
import net from 'node:net';

export class TcpClient {
  private _client?: net.Socket;

  connect(options: net.TcpNetConnectOpts): void {
    this._client = net.createConnection(options);

    this._client.on('data', data => console.log('Received:', data.toString()));
    this._client.on('error', error => console.error('Error:', error));
    this._client.on('close', () => console.log('TCP connection closed'));
  }

  async send(data: any): Promise<void> {
    if (!this._client || this._client.destroyed) {
      throw new Error('TCP client is not connected');
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._client!.write(
        JSON.stringify(data),
        error => (error ? reject(error) : resolve()),
      );
    });
  }
}

What Happens

The client successfully connects to the server.
The client sends a message (e.g., {"pattern":"get-all-platforms","data":{}}), but the server does not process or respond to it.
If I send data to a non-existent port, the client immediately throws a connection error, confirming that the connection is working when the port is correct.

What I’ve Tried

Ensured that the pattern and data structure in the message matches what the server expects.
Verified that the @MessagePattern on the server is registered correctly.
Checked the server logs, but they show no sign of the message being received.

Key Details

The TcpClient uses net from Node.js for sending data over TCP.
The server is set up with the @nestjs/microservices package.

How can I debug this issue further? Is there something I might be missing in the client-server communication setup?
